# Access CURLOPT_POSTFIELD vars in remote script?

Tags: php, curl

How do I retrieve the POSTFEILD var contents in the remote script (target_url.php) to use it within the same remote script?

I am doing something like this below.  It returns no errors.

```
//Have tried multiple ways to setup the POSTFEILD argument, such as:

$data = array('var'=>'varcontents');
$post_arg = http_build_query($data) . "\n";

//and

$post_arg = 'var ='  . urlencode($varcontents);


//create cURL connection
$ch = curl_init('http://www.remotedomain.com/target_url.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_arg);

//perform the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: Have a look at the `$_POST`-array :) (http://fr.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have been trying $_POST, but no luck.

Comment: If you POST 'var' to target_url.php, it's available there as `$varcontents = $_POST['var']?` - $_POST itself is just an assciative array.

Comment: Yes, that has been my usage.  But still get nothing coming thru to the remote script.

Comment: Could you please post the code from target_url.php that handles the request?

Comment: $homesite = $_POST['postvar'];

Comment: Please see my answer, I think you didn't set curl up correctly (especially the `CURLOPT_POST` is missing).

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this same problem and here is the solution I found, thought I would share it with you:

Use

```
$varcontent = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

in your target_url.php, that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

using

```
<?php
$post_arg = http_build_query( array('var'=>'varcontents') );
//create cURL connection
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/target_url.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_arg);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

as the "client" and

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

as target_url.php the output is

```
string(186) "<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  'var' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'varcontents'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
</pre>"
```

(reminds me to deactivate that xdebug option ;-) ), so in target_url.php the parameters are accessible via $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your curl-setup seems not quite right. Try this:

```
$post_data = http_build_query(array('var'=>'varcontents'));
$url = 'http://www.remotedomain.com/target_url.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And in your target_url.php, als already said:

```
$varcontent = $_POST['var'];
```

Comment: Still not working.  The urlencoding of the remote URL takes away my web page, it just goes blank.  What I am trying to do is share web pages on my main server with my other websites.  Only cosmetic stuff changes with the other websites, logo graphics, names, etc.  The site visitor will start one of my other webpages, but its content will be pulled from my central site, and the cosmetics need to change by sending a variable of some sort to the central site.  I've tried a lot of options, but still no luck passing the necessary variable.

Comment: Another note, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = TRUE also makes the resultant webpage go blank.